# ActionBar get current icon, findviewbyid

Tags: android, android-actionbar, imageview, icons, findviewbyid

I know how to set the icon of the actionbar, but how do I determine what icon is currently there? I don't see an accessor like `getIcon` , I think it is possible to find the icon view by id, since I've done this with the search widget in the actionbar, but I wouldn't know what id to call.

Comment: This is a good question, I didn't realize that Android didn't make the getters for the icon/logo public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source code of `ActionBarView.HomeView` you should be able to get `ImageView` of icon by `android.R.id.home`.

So code may look like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
Drawable dr = imageView.getDrawable();
```

Not sure if this will work with support libraries

Comment: thanks, not using the support libraries, BYE BYE GINGERBREAD :)