# How to get the icon of the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my activity, the ActionBar's title and icon is set programmatically. To save both in onStop() I have to get the values back. The title can be read by getActionBar.getTitle(). But there is no getIcon() method provided by the ActionBar. How can I get the Icon?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      getActionBar().setTitle("MyActualTitle");
      getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo1);
      ...
    }

    protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    String actualTitle = getActionBar().getTitle().toString();
    int actualIcon = getActionBar().getIcon(); //Missing
    // Save both in SharedPreferences 
    ...
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349630/actionbar-get-current-icon-findviewbyid

Comment: I need the Resource ID, and it must work API version independent.

Comment: try it and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onCreate keep a member value:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo1);
mIcon = R.drawable.logo1
```

and use it to store value on shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that is

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
Drawable dr = mImageView.getDrawable();
```